# Create group in SCOM 2007 R2 that targets windows computer but is populated based on an installed service

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, scom

I am trying to create a group in SCOM 2007 R2 that targets the Windows Computer class but is populated based on a certain service being installed. I want the group to be populated dynamically based on the service discovery information.

I can create a group that targets the service and populates based on the computer that has that service installed, but I want to actually target the computer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that a custom discovery needed to be created based on the Windows Computer object that evaluated a registry key for the service. The Windows Computer object was automatically cloned into a new class that inherited all attributes of the base class plus the additional registry attribute that I defined.

After that, it was just a matter of creating a group that targeted that new class.